# Python urllib won't download file due to permissions, but wget will

Tags: python, http, urllib2, wget

I'm trying to download an MP3 file, via its URL, using Python's `urllib2`.

```
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
output = open(dst,'wb')
output.write(mp3file.read())
output.close()
```

I'm getting a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error. 
Trying `urllib` also fails, but silently.

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, dst)
```

However, if I use `wget`, I can download the file successfully.

I've noted the general differences between the two methods mentioned in "[Difference between Python urllib.urlretrieve() and wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777116/difference-between-python-urllib-urlretrieve-and-wget)", but they don't seem to apply here.

Is `wget` doing something to negotiate permissions that `urllib2` doesn't do? If so, what, and how do I replicate this in `urllib2`?

Comment: That is completely dependent on the server, have you tried `wget --verbose` to see what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried adding headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden

Comment: It appears `wget`'s default output level is verbose, so it's not giving me anything extra when the flag is given explicitly. I'll try playing around with the headers...

Answer (score 1):

Could be something on the server side -  blocking python user agent for example. Try using `wget` user agent : `Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)` .

In Python 2:

```
import urllib

# Change header for User-Agent
class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
url = "http://www.example.com/test_file"
fname = "test_file"
urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()
urllib.urlretrieve(url, fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me (I'm using python3.5). `wget` works fine.

It's not (I assume) a huge problem for me - surely I can still do a `system()` and use `wget` to get the data, with some file renaming and munging.

But in case anyone else is suffering from the same problem, these are the errors I get from the above snippet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mksynt.py", line 10, in <module>
    class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'FancyURLopener'
```

I see that the original answer was only promised to work in python2.