# Download file in python using urllib2 vs wget

Tags: python, download, wget, urllib2, urllib3

I am trying to download an online file in python. I have seen solutions using urllib2 for python 2 and wget. If my purpose is just to download the file, is there any advantage of using urllib2 instead of wget. To me using wget package seems simpler. However, most of the online solutions I see are using urllib2 and urllib with python 3. I am more inclined towards wget as it works for both python 2 and python 3.

This question is different from the question marked as duplicate of this as I have asked for difference with respect to wget, while the other question does not address the relationship with respect to wget package.

Comment: `wget` requires you to shell out to an external application. Python programs should always prefer to call Python libraries rather than shelling out.

Comment: the `requests` library is great as well, available for Python 2 & 3

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510727/119527) shows exactly how to use `urllib` from Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what do you mean by shelling out. Does it mean wget runs some shell command at the back. wget is also a standard python library, right? Then how does one differentiate between python and non-python library? Though, I get wget is not a good option from what I have read by now.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realize this existed: [`wget`](https://pypi.org/project/wget/), the "pure python library". I thought you were referring to [`wget`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html), the command-line utility.  Regardless, `requests` is much more common.

Comment: @wim  the link duplicate question mentions nothing about usefulness of urllib against wget, which is my question. Then why the question has been marked duplicate?

Comment: I did not mark it as duplicate, other user did. It's a bug in stackexchange that I was listed :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use `wget` then you'd end up writing way much more code when needing to decode the errors that happen with it, than you'd need for a Python library.

However, when it comes to `urllib` - first of all, are you sure you *really* need to support Python 2? Python 2 is obsolete.

If you *really really believe* that you do, then perhaps you can use a compatibility library such as [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) or the [`future`](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#urllib-module)

And you should consider alternatives too - the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library is superior to the `urllib` and provides the same interface for Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Anitti After some more reading I am convinced to use requests. However, I am curious about what kinds of errors are you talking about and why it would be difficult to debug with wget when it is present in PyPI and should be up-to-date. If you can give some instance. Also, saw some answers, but only a few of them, suggesting to not use urllib as it is less mature than wget (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777116/difference-between-python-urllib-urlretrieve-and-wget). Can you comment on this point.